# How to add new data after fetch and save old ones on the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have react component `LogMessage` that sends request to the server for checking if new log messages presented.

```
export default function LogMessage () {
    const [logMessage, setLogMessage] = useState({});
    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8989/get-log');
            const data = await response.json();
            setLogMessage(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }

    };
    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            fetchData();
          }, 1000);
          return () => clearInterval(interval);
      }, []);

    return (
        <div className="log">
            <p>Logger</p>
            <div className="log_wrapper">
                {Object.entries(logMessage).map(([key, message]) => (
                    <span>{message}</span>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

With every fetch, my previously displayed messages re-rendered by new ones instead of adding them to those already displayed on the page.
The response looks like:

```
{
    "message1": "12:48:49:271  some text",
    "message2": "12:48:49:458  some text",
    "message3": "12:48:49:758  some text",
    "message4": "12:48:49:913  some text",
    "message5": "12:48:50:024  some text"
}
```

If there are not any new messages in response to fetch, then the empty json returns {}.

Is there a way to display new messages and save old ones on the page?

Comment: you can append your old messages to the `fetchData()` function when you use `setLogMessage(data);` use a variable `const allMessage = [...logMessages, ...data].filter(...)` you should remove the duplicates if any (check IDs or sth similar) and `setLogMessage(allMessage)` should have old data and new data in place every 1000 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the new data with the existing data in the state.

```
setLogMessages(prev => ({ ...prev, ...data }));
```

This will add the new data if any to the previous state value.

Comment: I tryied your solution and it works but save in the memory for example 100k+ messages can be problematic in terms of memory

Comment: Then you need to limit the number of messages displayed in the screen or else you can implement pagination if you need to display all messages.